Ability to use WARP over SOCKS5
I have a VPS on Ubuntu with VLESS (Xray), SOCKS5 (dante) and Cloudflare WARP (as a docker container; using port 1080) installed.
These two commands show me the correct IP of WARP: curl --socks5 localhost:1080 https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace/ (I also get warp=on here) and curl --socks5 localhost:1080 https://ifconfig.io.
I'm using Foxyproxy add-on for Firefox to connect to this SOCKS5, and all sites detect IP of VPS.
I know that there is a way to use WARP over VLESS so that the end site sees my IP as WARP's IP, not VPS's . Along the same lines, I would like to ask if there is a way to use WARP over SOCKS5 exists? I've tried changing dante's config to this:
internal: 0.0.0.0 port = 1234 # port I'm using to connect to SOCKS5 from my browser
external: 127.0.0.1 # and here I've tried 'localhost' and 'docker0'

And no effect - all IP databases detect IP of VPS. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Or is there no way to use WARP over SOCKS5 at all?
